# How does all() in python work on empty lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am looking at the behavior of the `all` function in Python and it's behavior struck me as not very intuitive when it comes to empty lists. I would assume there is a good rationale and deliberation that went into the decision for such a choice and probably there is a solid mathematical explanation in some form. I am curious to know what is the foundation for such behaviors where comparisons with an empty set results in `true` results.

I am referring to the following python code

```
all(a==2 for a in my_list)
```

I expect the above code to return True if all the elements in my_list are 2.
but when I make my_list empty and run it as

```
my_list = []
all(a==2 for a in my_list)
```

it returns True as well. I am confused with this behaviour. Is it not supposed to return False as there is no element in my_list with value 2?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's true because for every element in the list, all 0 of them, they all are equal to 2.

You can think of [all](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) being implemented as:

```
def all(my_list, condition):
  for a in my_list:
    if not condition(a):
      return False
  return True
```

Whereas [any](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) is:

```
def any(my_list, condition):
  for a in my_list:
    if condition(a):
      return True
  return False
```

That is to say, `all` is innocent until proven guilty, and `any` is guilty until proven innocent.

Comment: Love the analogy! Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 8):

"all" applied to an empty list is "vacuously true", as is easily confirmed:

```
>>> all([])
True
```

Similarly, "if 0 = 1 then the moon is square" is true. More generally, "all P are Q" -- if there are no P's then the statement is considered true, as it can be captured formally as "For all x, if x is P then x is Q". Ultimately, these are true because the conditional logical operator (if-then) evaluates to True whenever the antecedent (the first clause) is False: "if False then True" evaluates to True. Recall that "if A then B" is equivalent to "(not A) or B".

*Added 1-2022*
In the case of `all` and Python lists, the boolean value of `all(my_list)` is the value of

```
"for all items `x` in `my_list`, the value of `x` is truthy".
```

When `my_list` is empty, that value is True. Again, "for all" and `all` make no existence claim.

In Python pseudocode, `all` works roughly like this:

```
val = True
for x in my_list:
    if not x:
        val = False
        break
# assert val == all(my_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider a recursive definition of `all`:

```
def all(L):
    if L:
        return L[0] and all(L[1:])
    else:
        ???
```

If every element in `L` is true, then it must be true that both the first item in `L` is true, *and* that `all(L[1:])` is true. This is easy to see for a list with several items, but what about a list with *one* item. Clearly, every item is true if the only item is true, but how does our recursive formulation work in that case? Defining `all([])` to be true makes the algorithm work.

Another way to look at it is that for any list `L` for which `all(L)` is *not* true, we should be able to identify at least one element, `a`, which is not true. However, there is no such `a` in `L` when `L` is empty, so we are justified in saying that `all([])` is true.

The same arguments work for `any`. If `any(L)` is true, we should be able to identify at least one element in `L` that is true. But since we cannot for an empty list `L`, we can say that `any([])` is false. A recursive implementation of `any` backs this up:

```
def any(L):
    if L:
        return L[0] or any(L[1:])
    else:
        return False
```

If `L[0]` is true, we can return true without ever making the recursive call, so assume `L[0]` is false. The only way we ever reach the base case is if no element of `L` is true, so
we must return `False` if we reach it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is already well explained by other answers. As a quick fix you can use:

```
my_list and all(a==2 for a in my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [office documents](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all).

all(iterable)
Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty). Equivalent to:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

New in version 2.5.

any(iterable)
Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False. Equivalent to:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

New in version 2.5.